# Spring boot + oauth2 : Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement a authentication-server using spring boot, spring cloud security and spring cloud oauth2.

I am getting below error when I try to hit http://localhost:8080/auth/oauth/token from postman

> {
>       "error": "unauthorized",
>       "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
>   }

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> . 
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.teckink.tp</groupId>
<artifactId>tp-auth-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tp-auth-server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M9</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

Starter(Main) class:

```
package com.teckink.tp.authserver;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class App {
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/user" }, produces = "application/json")
    public Map<String, Object> user(OAuth2Authentication user) {
        Map<String, Object> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("user", user.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        userInfo.put("authorities", AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(user.getUserAuthentication().getAuthorities()));
        return userInfo;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

OAuth2Config class which defines client and its secret:

```
package com.teckink.tp.authserver.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("eagleeye")
                .secret("thisissecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
                .scopes("webclient", "mobileclient");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
      endpoints
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurer class which defines in-memory user, password and roles:

```
package com.teckink.tp.authserver.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

   @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("john.carnell").password("password1").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("william.woodward").password("password2").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
}
```

I am calling Rest API from POSTMAN as below-
Request with authentication screen show as below :
[image]

Request with form-data as below 
[image]

Comment: If possible, please upload a reproducible sample project to GitHub.

Comment: @Prithvi - Do you think you can help me on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090739/spring-boot-jwt-security-full-authentication-is-required

Comment: @KyleAnderson - Can you please help me on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090739/spring-boot-jwt-security-full-authentication-is-required

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your sample app when you run, you would have got the following exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped
>   for the id "null"

In spring-security-core:5.0, the default PasswordEncoder is built as a DelegatingPasswordEncoder. Hence when you store the users in memory, you are providing the passwords in plain text and then when you are trying to retrieve the encoder from the DelegatingPasswordEncoder to validate the password it can't find one.

More details in this link [Password Encoding](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-encoding)

To address this , for a production implementation you should activate an instance of `BCryptPasswordEncoder`

For development, you can try out the following changes so that you can override password encoding by adding `{noop}` to the password value. This will treat the password by activating the `NoOpPasswordEncoder` instead of the default `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` and will treat your password as plain text.

OAuth2Config class

```
clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("eagleeye")
            .secret("{noop}thisissecret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
            .scopes("webclient", "mobileclient");
```

WebSecurityConfigurer class

```
 auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("john.carnell"). password("{noop}password1").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("william.woodward").password("{noop}password2").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
```

Now when you try from Postman, you would be able to generate token
[image]

**EDIT**

Github project with a working demo [here](https://github.com/Chids-gs/OAuth2Demo-StackOverflow)

Comment: I am not getting any error in console. 
Also I prepend {noop} in secret and password but still getting same error in response: "Full authentication is required to access this resource
".

Comment: have uploaded link with a github project. See what is different from the codebase that you are using.

Comment: I was hitting wrong endpoint: http://localhost:8080/auth/oauth/token. It changed it to http://localhost:8080/oauth/token and then I got error you mentioned above. I solve that error by prefixing {noop}

Comment: @Chids - Can you please me on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090739/spring-boot-jwt-security-full-authentication-is-required

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue. the url is wrong, change to http://localhost:8080/oauth/token then it's OK.
I got this sample from book which is giving the wrong url. just remove the "/auth"

Answer (score 1):

The following changes fixed this issue for me when reading Spring Microservices in Action by John Carnell.

Changed the following property

**application.yml**

```
server:
  contextPath: /auth
```

To

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /auth
```

And I've also added {noop} to every secret/password and now it works!

**WebSecurityConfigurer.java**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("john.carnell").password("{noop}password1").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("william.woodward").password("{noop}password2").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
```

**OAuth2Config.java**

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("eagleeye")
                .secret("{noop}thisissecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
                .scopes("webclient", "mobileclient");
    }
```

I am using Spring Cloud Hoxton SR11

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your grant type is listed as "passwor" and not "password" in your post
Can you please correct that and try once more?

Comment: I changed it to "password". Still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

It's weird same-thing happened here. I solved it by using curl command.

```
curl -v -X POST  http://url:8080/api/oauth/token -u "yourclientid:yourclient_secret"   -d "grant_type=password"   -d "username=yourusername" -d "password=yourpassword"
```

Or 
If you want it in postman go to Authorization --> select type  OAUTH2  -->  Get Access Token
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYsGb.jpg)